# c# deployment with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment

I've recently developed a c# application that uses a mysql connector. I've run into some issues with other computers not having the Mysql.Data library. So my question, what is the best way to deploy a c# application that uses these Mysql.Data libraries? Install the mysql connector on every computer? Is there some way I can make c# package these together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector can be distributed as a private DLL. Just change its property to "Copy to Output" and distribute it along with the rest of your installation files.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy MySql.Data.dll along with your EXE file.